# Drawing a box with \rule: can I add a black outline?

Tags: color

I am using the following command to create little boxes:

```
\newcommand\crule[3][black]{\textcolor{#1}{\rule{#2}{#3}}}
```

So far, they are always filled with one colour. Is there a possibility to keep the colour of the fill adaptable but always have a black outline around it?

Comment: You should look at the `xcolor` documentation: it has an `\fcolorbox`  command, for which you can choose independently the fill colour and the frame colour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably [@Bernard solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/38908/bernard) is the better one. But playing a bit, and following the respected tradition of [never reading manuals `;-P`](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3973372#3973372),...

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand\cruleblacky[3][black]{\begingroup
    \fboxsep=0pt\raisebox{\fboxrule}{%
    \fbox{\textcolor{#1}{%
    \rule{\dimexpr #2-2\fboxrule\relax}{\dimexpr #3-2\fboxrule\relax}%
}}}\endgroup}
\newcommand\crule[3][black]{\textcolor{#1}{\rule{#2}{#3}}}

\begin{document}
\crule[red]{10pt}{10pt}
\cruleblacky[red]{10pt}{10pt}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice that most of the complexity is to match exactly the same behavior of the old `\crule` command for size and position.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to increase the thickness of the line? (My problem with \fcolorbox btw is that I need an empty box and for some reason it doesn't align with my text properly...)

Comment: Try `\fboxrule=4pt` just after `\fboxsep=0pt`...